# How can I programmatically retrieve an EventInfo for an event without hard coding its name?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Given an interface:

```
IEventProvider
{
    event EventHandler<string> StringAvailable;

    void RequestString();
}
```

I want to retrieve an `EventInfo` for `StringAvailable` through some method that can be called like this: `EventInfo ei = GetEventInfo(providerInstance.StringAvailable)` or something to that effect. I don't want to have to pass a string containing its name.

I've tried to abuse lambdas and expression trees to extract the name of the event being passed in but to no avail. Because events are not first class members in C# this is proving to be difficult. I just help finding a way to get the name of the event at run-time with code that can be statically validated by the compiler to ensure the event exists at compile time.

My workaround right now is to remove all of the events from the classes I want to work with and change them to `Action<T>`. This is less than ideal though.

For those of you wondering why I'm doing this, I want to allow classes that use the event based asynchronous pattern to be adapted to async/await automatically at run-time using IL generation. In my example interface above, the adapter would wrap `RequestString` and `StringAvailable` and expose `public async Task<string> RequestStringAsync()` using `DynamicMethod`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the ProviderInfo Instance to a method which gets the EventInfo(s) per reflection.

Here are three examples:

```
var singleEvent = GetEventInfo(providerInstance);

public static EventInfo GetEventInfo(IEventProvider eventProvider)
{
    var type = eventProvider.GetType();
    return type.GetEvent(nameof(eventProvider.StringAvailable));
}
```

This one gets the event with the hard-coded nameof-operator.

```
var singleEventWithName = GetEventInfo(providerInstance, nameof(providerInstance.StringAvailable));

public static EventInfo GetEventInfo(IEventProvider eventProvider, string name)
{
    var type = eventProvider.GetType();
    return type.GetEvent(name);
}
```

Here you could pass the name with the nameof-operator.

```
var allEvents = GetEventInfos(providerInstance);

public static EventInfo[] GetEventInfos(IEventProvider eventProvider)
{
    return eventProvider.GetType().GetEvents();
}
```

And this one returns just all the EventInfos of the provider.

I hope this helps.

**Edit**

Better would be:

```
var eventInfo = GetEventInfo(nameof(providerInstance.StringAvailable));

public static EventInfo GetEventInfo(string name)
{
    return typeof(IEventProvider).GetEvent(name);
}
```

Comment: Oh my gosh I didn't know `nameof` was a thing! That's awesome. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, I would write an extension method like this

```
 public static class Ext
{
    public static Task<string> RequestStringAsync(this IEventProvider cls)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
        EventHandler<string> handler = null;

        handler = (o, s) =>
        {
            tcs.SetResult(s);
            cls.StringAvailable -= handler;
        };

        cls.StringAvailable += handler;

        cls.RequestString();

        return tcs.Task;
    }
}
```

and use it

```
public class MyEventProvider : IEventProvider
{
    public event EventHandler<string> StringAvailable;

    public void RequestString()
    {
        var temp = StringAvailable;
        if (temp != null) temp(this, "aaaaa");
    }
}
```

---

```
var p = new MyEventProvider();
var str = await p.RequestStringAsync();
```

Comment: Yeah that's pretty much what I wanted to do, but dynamically at run-time. The reason for the automation is because I have hundreds of events to adapt in this way and didn't want to write them all by hand.